# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Делаю приложение с использованием Spring Boot и Hibernate версии 6.1.6.FINAL. При попытке сохранить новый объект сущности `Purchase` в БД получаю ошибку:

> org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ru.terentyev.playtoxapp.entities.Purchase

Даже примерно не предполагаю в чем проблема.
В интернете пишут, что, возможно, устанавливается id объекта перед сохранением - такого нет. Или пишут, что нужно использовать `(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)` - в моем случае не работает.
Читал, что использовать метод `.merge()` не рекомендуется, тем более он все равно не работает в моем случае и получаю ту же ошибку.

Вот цепочка от создания объекта `Purchase` до попытки сохранения:

**Контроллер, создающий этот объект и отправляющий его в представление:**

```
    @GetMapping("/products/{id}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("product", productService.findById(id));     
        model.addAttribute("purchase", new Purchase());
        return "viewProduct";
    }
```

**Представление:**

```
<div th:object="${product}">
    <h3 th:text="*{name}"></h3><br>
    <h5 th:text="|Цена: *{price}руб.|"></h5>
    <h5 th:text="|Остаток: *{stock}|"></h5>
    <span th:text="*{description}"></span><br><br>
    <form sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:method="POST" th:action="@{/products/{id}/buy(id=${product.id})}" th:object="${purchase}">
        <span th:text="${purchase.product}"></span>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}">Вы выбрали больше, чем есть в наличии</span>
        <!--<input type="hidden" th:field="*{product}" th:value="${productOfPurchase}"/>-->
        <input type="number" placeholder="Кол-во для покупки" value="Количество" th:field="*{count}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Купить"/>
        </form>
    <br><br><br>
    <a sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')" th:href="@{/admin/products/{id}/edit(id=*{id})}">Изменить</a>
    
    
    </div>
```

**Другой контроллер, принимающий этот объект обратно из представления:**

```
    @PostMapping("/products/{id}/buy")
    public String buy(@ModelAttribute Purchase purchase, @PathVariable int id
            , BindingResult br, @AuthenticationPrincipal PersonDetails personDetails) {
        purchase.setProduct(productService.findById(id));
        purchase.setOwner(personDetails.getPerson());
        if (purchase.getProduct().getStock() < purchase.getCount()) {
            br.addError(new ObjectError("globalError", "Вы выбрали кол-во товара большее, чем есть в наличии"));
            if (br.hasErrors()) return "redirect:/products/" + String.valueOf(purchase.getProduct().getId());
            return "viewProduct";
        }
        purchaseService.buy(purchase);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

**PurchaseService:**

```
    public void buy(Purchase purchase) {
        System.out.println(purchase + " " + purchase.getProduct()
        + " " + purchase.getProduct().getId() + " " + purchase.getOwner() + " " 
        + purchase.getCount());
        purchaseRepository.save(purchase);
    }
```

**PurchaseRepository:**

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void save(Purchase purchase) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(purchase);
        
    }
```

**Вот сущность Purchase:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "purchases")
public class Purchase {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person owner;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "purchase", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Product product;
    private LocalDate date;
    private int count;
    
    public Purchase(){}
```

**Person:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private transient String passwordConfirm; 
    @Column(name = "is_admin", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
    private boolean admin;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Purchase> purchases;

    public Person() {}
```

**Product:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
    
    private static String picturesUploadPath = ResourceBundle.getBundle("upload").getString("upload.path");
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int price;
    private int stock;
    private transient MultipartFile[] pictures = new MultipartFile[5];
    private String[] picturesPath = new String[5];
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Purchase purchase;
    
    public Product() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите на сущности Person и Product. Если у них есть ссылка на Purchase, возможно, что она нулевая. Что то с ними скорее всего.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: выложил классы сущностей